# How do I make an apple script to save screenshots to clipboard?

Tags: macos, applescript

Right now, on Macs, when you click shift-command-4, you can select an area on the screen to take a screenshot of. The photo is then saved on your desktop.

How can I make an apple script so that it also saves the photo on my clipboard?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the screenshot that appears on your desktop to automatically be placed into the clipboard?

Comment: press control-shift-command-4 to save the screen shot to the clipboard

Comment: I tried this and dislocated my thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the terminal tool ***screencapture*** is your friend. You can write a script like

```
do shell script "screencapture -ci"
```

and start that. The parameters used in this script are doing the following:

- -c      Force screen capture to go to the clipboard
- -i      Capture screen interactively, by selection or window. The control key will cause the screen shot to go to the clipboard. The space key will toggle between mouse selection and window selection modes. The escape key will cancel the interactive screen shot.

You can find all parameters for the screen capture tool using `man screencapture` in **Terminal.app**, i.e. the parameter `P` would open the screen shot directly in **Preview.app**.

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg